# Enter key to append container in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note: I am quite new to javascript so, apologies if this seems trivial.

I have some code that adds a new container to an existing one on the click of a mouse button.

Using the .click() function, a new class is added, then resized and finally, appended to the parent container.

Is there a way for this also to be done with the 'enter' key?

```
  C.prototype.addSolutionContainerTo = function ($container) {
    var self = this;

    self.$solutionContainer = $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'h5p-guess-answer-solution-container',
    }).click(function () {
      $(this).addClass('h5p-guess-answer-showing-solution').html(self.params.solutionText);
      self.trigger('resize');
    }).appendTo($container);
  };

  return C;
})
```

One solution I have found is something along the lines of:

```
$(this).keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $(this).addClass('h5p-guess-answer-showing-solution').html(this.params.solutionText);
    self.trigger('resize'); 
  }
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and won't even throw a console log.

Comment: Is the keypress event actually being fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the enter key to work no matter what element is "focused" on the page, you might consider attaching the keypress event to the document, like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) $button.click();
});
```

Comment: great, thanks! how about restricting it to only when the original container is focused?

Comment: Keypress events bubble, so you can attach your listener to the highest level DOM element which makes sense. Maybe to a `<form>` element, or a wrapper `<div>`

Comment: would it be possible to append the $solutionContainer again? I have the following but it doesn't seem to work:

    $(this).keypress(function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).addClass('h5p-guess-answer-showing-solution').html(this.params.solutionText);
        self.trigger('resize');
      }
    });

Comment: With something like `$(this).keypress`, it is completely impossible to have any idea of what `this` is supposed to be. If it's not working correctly, my guess is that you might be attaching the listener to the wrong DOM element. Maybe you could have an id for the container, and use something like `$('#wrapperId').keypress()`?

Comment: Oh, something I noticed just now...looks like you are doing your `.append()` after you are trying to attach your listeners. You might try appending the node into the DOM before attaching your listeners. Just a thought.